# Java and regex lexer

Tags: java, regex, lexer

I am trying to make some sort of Lexer in Java using regex for a custom markdown "language" I'm making, it's my first time working with this stuff so a little lost on a few things.
An example of a possible syntax in it is:
`Some <#000000>*text* [<#ffffff>Some more](action: Other <#gradient>text) and **finally** some more <#000>text!`
I was able to capture a few things, for example I'm using `(?<hex><#\w+>)` to capture the "hex" and `(?<action>\[[^]]*]\([^]]*\))` to get the entire "action" block.
My problem is being able to capture it all together, like, how to combine it all. For example the lexer needs to output something like:

```
TEXT - Some
HEX - <#000000>
TEXT - *text*
ACTION - [<#ffffff>Some more](action: Other <#gradient>text)
TEXT - and **finally** some more
HEX - <#000>
TEXT - text!
```

I'll handle the bold and italic later.
Would love just some suggestions on how to combine all of them!

Comment: You could create (named) capturing groups for all the parts `^(.*?) (?<hex1><#\w+>)(\*[^*]*\*) (?<action>\[[^]]*]\([^]]*\)) (.*?) (?<hex2><#\w+>)(.*)$` https://regex101.com/r/iocBCR/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hey thank you! Tough that means it needs to be exactly like the example I sent right? For example changing the order or adding new tags won't be recognized.

Comment: The current pattern is depending on all the parts being present in that order. You might use an alternation to make it more flexible `(?<hex><#\w+>)|(?<action>\[[^]]*]\([^]]*\))|(?<text>[\w!* ]+)` https://regex101.com/r/JWHNP9/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Oh okay, I'm starting to understand now thank you! If you wanna post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be using an alternation matching each of the separate parts, and for the text part use for example a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\w!* ]+`

In Java, you could check for the name of the capturing group.

```
(?<hex><#\w+>)|(?<action>\[[^]]*]\([^]]*\))|(?<text>[\w!* ]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<hex><#\w+>)` Capture group `hex`, match # and 1+ word chars
- `|` Or
- `(?<action>` Capture group `action`

  - `\[[^]]*]\([^]]*\)` Match `[`...`]` followed by `(...)`
- `)` Close group
- `|` Or
- `(?<text>[\w!* ]+)` Capture group `text`, match 1+ times any char listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWHNP9/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/6rjsya)

Example code:

```
String regex = "(?<hex><#\\w+>)|(?<action>\\[[^]]*]\\([^]]*\\))|(?<text>[\\w!* ]+)";
String string = "Some <#000000>*text* [<#ffffff>Some more](action: Other <#gradient>text) and **finally** some more <#000>text!";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group("hex") != null) {
        System.out.println("HEX - " + matcher.group("hex"));    
    }
    if (matcher.group("text") != null) {
        System.out.println("TEXT - " + matcher.group("text"));  
    }
    if (matcher.group("action") != null) {
        System.out.println("ACTION - " + matcher.group("action"));  
    }
}
```

Output

```
TEXT - Some 
HEX - <#000000>
TEXT - *text* 
ACTION - [<#ffffff>Some more](action: Other <#gradient>text)
TEXT -  and **finally** some more 
HEX - <#000>
TEXT - text!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **Regex- Capturing groups** like this
`^(.*?) (?<hex1><#\w+>)(\*[^*]*\*) (?<action>\[[^]]*]\([^]]*\)) (.*?) (?<hex2><#\w+>)(.*)$`
To get a better understanding refer this [Click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm)